# Server error upon firing AJAX event in ZF2

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework2

When I load my page, everything's fine. However, something goes wrong when I fire an AJAX event in a js file (in my public folder) that calls an action in my controller.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No RouteMatch instance provided' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Url.php:86
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Zend\View\Helper\Url-&gt;__invoke()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(400): call_user_func_array(Object(Zend\View\Helper\Url), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\module\Application\view\layout\layout.phtml(25): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer-&gt;__call('url', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\module\Application\view\layout\layout.phtml(25): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer-&gt;url()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(507): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(201): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer-&gt;render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\zendframework\ze in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Url.php</b> on line <b>86</b><br />
```

Here's my js:

```
$('.expand, .ccid, .name').click(function(){    
    var CCID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    CCID = parseInt(CCID);

    if($.inArray(CCID,$expanded) > -1){
        foldin(CCID);
    } else {
        $.post('expand', {           // Call to "expand" action in controller
            id: CCID
        },function(data){
            if(data.hasOwnProperty('info')){   
                expand(data.info);
            } else {
                console.log('Can\'t find customer info.');
            }
        },'json'); 
    }
});
```

Below is line 25 og my layout.phtml:

```
if($this->url() !== '/auth'){
    echo 'stuff';
}
```

I've put this there to check if the user's on the login page, so it doesn't echo a certain div if they are. There's probably a better way to do this that I don't know of, but I still don't understand why it gives me trouble when I fire the AJAX event while it doesn't normally. It also does it very inconsistently. Sometimes the event works for ages and then suddenly it'll shoot the above error.

Anyone know what this is about? What does the event have to do with rendering layout.php?

Comment: can you show your js code, and why are you testing for `url` in the layout file?

Comment: I've added the js now, why I check for the url is explained below that block.

Comment: you should ideally handle your `if` scenario using a separate layout file for the login page. that's what i usually do

Comment: That does make sense sorta, but I just don't like making a separate file if the only differece is a single div. Just irks me.

Comment: You should check out how android views are done :) you will be irking all day :) the easiest way around is to throw u r line 25 inside a try catch block but that doesn't help your case. i've never used a RouteMatch Object but looks like you wanna have to visit here http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Mvc.Router.Http.RouteMatch.html

Comment: Ahhh, ZF2. Never ceases to sling something new to learn in my face just as I think that I get everything. Thanks.